# Determine needed # of extra bytes to conduct buffer overflow attack (homework)

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

For assistance in completing Level 0 of [this buffer overflow project (.pdf)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c_91R8NqU7J8KgJKEJ0wrtMcmQ3F31fr) in Assembly, I'm using [this guide](https://github.com/quinnliu/bufferBomb/blob/master/level0.md).

> Goal = provide a string longer than getbuf can handle  (`getbuf()` takes
>   an input of 32 characters), causing an overflow and pushing the rest
>   of the string onto the stack where you can then control where the
>   function getbuf returns after exection (we want to call the `smoke()` function).

When I get to step 2 of the guide, I need to calculate how many additional characters my input string should have, on top of the original 32-character input, in order to execute buffer overflow and call `smoke()`.

**(Step 2 Excerpt)**:

[image]

In my case, I find `startingAddressOfBufVariable` to be `0x55683ddc` and `%ebp` is `0x55683df0`.

I calculate `buffer size = addressAt%ebp+4 - startingAddressOfBufVariable`, which is `0x55683df0+4 - 0x55683ddc = 0x18 = 24`.

In the next step, I'm supposed to subtract 32 from that result to determine how many additional characters (on top of the original 32) that my input string should have. However, `24 - 32 = -8`. I get a negative number! I'm not sure what to do with that. *Subtract* 8 characters from my 32-character input string? I'm trying to conduct overflow, so that doesn't make sense.

[image]

For testing/guessing purposes, I moved on with the guide, pretending that the `-8` result I got was actually a positive `8`. So I moved on with the guide, intending to add 8 characters on top of my 32-character string.

Knowing the address of my `smoke()` function to be `0x08048b2b`, I created my input file as such, per the instructions in step 4 (though why did they change `aa` to `61`?):

```
perl -e 'print "AA "x32, "BB "x4, "CC "x4, "2b 8b 04 08" '>hex3
```

**(Step 4 Excerpt:)**
[image]

So, **Am I using the incorrect math in Step 2 of the guide? Are my addresses I'm using in the math incorrect? If they are correct, how do I interpret the `-8` result, and what does the `-8` result mean, in terms of modifying my character input to execute the overflow attack?**

Comment: Are you stepping into `getbuf` before checking the values in step 2? I have a suspicion you're doing it before that which is why `ebp` is slightly off.

Comment: `'a' == 0x61` in ASCII encoding, and many other modern string encodings like UTF8 or almost all latin-letters encodings of windows keep the low 0-127 values compatible. But that means `61` is `"a"`, not `"aa"`. `"aa"` is `0x6161` (two bytes).  (just like `'A'` is `0x41` ... check any ASCII table to see how most of the English texts are encoded from letters into numbers in computers, because computers don't know any letter at all)

Comment: Reading more those pics, looks like there's some clash of ideas of author, sometimes using ASCII codes 0x41/0x61 of chars like a/A to get the "a/A" filling of stack memory, sometimes they just use the hexa value like 0xAA to fill the memory (which is usually displayed as dot "." in UTF8 linux debuggers as it's not valid 7 bit ASCII code and single byte displaying like memory area doesn't make sense to compose code-points in UTF8 way, where several bytes may form just one letter). Depends how you check memory, with your current way displaying dword values 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC may be more "visible".

Comment: If you would display that memory as "string" instead (many debuggers offer two-pane memory view, usually with numeric values on left, and ASCII "string" interpretation of those values on right), then values like 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, ... would produce in the ASCII interpreted pane letters a, b, c, ... (making the filling more "visible" there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They write in the example C code that the buffer size is 12. It would make sense that you would have to infer the buffer size from the registers. Maybe try again with a base string size of 0x18?

Comment: That was a bit embarrassing. I should have read my original instructions more carefully to know that the buffer size was 12 in my assignment instead of 32 like it was in the guide. After I adjusted accordingly, and created my `hex3` file by first converting the letters to their respective hex values (`perl -e 'print "61 "x12, "62 "x4, "63 "x4, "64 "x4, "2b 8b 04 08" '>hex3`), I succeeded. Thank you!